# Using S3 as a database vs. database (e.g. MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nosql

Due to simple setup and low costs I am considering using AWS S3 bucket instead of a NoSQL database to save simple user settings as a JSON (around 30 documents).

I researched the following disadvantages of not using a database which are not relevant for my use case:

- Listing of buckets/files will cost you money.
- No updates - you cannot update a file, just replace it.
- No indexes.
- Versioning will cost you $$.
- No search
- No transactions
- No query API (SQL or NoSQL)

Are there any other disavantages of using a S3 bucket instead of a database?

Comment: From what you describe, you don't _need_ a database, indeed. But when you do (you need transactions or query DSL, etc), then you don't really have a choice.

Comment: If you just need a storage, you can try out [Minio](https://min.io/)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You are "considering using AWS S3 bucket instead of a NoSQL database", but the fact is that Amazon S3 effectively *is* a NoSQL database.

It is a very large Key-Value store. The Key is the filename, the Value is the contents of the file.

If your needs are simply "Store a value with this key" and "Retrieve a value with this key", then it would work just fine!

In fact, old orders on Amazon.com (more than a year old) are apparently archived to Amazon S3 since they are read-only (no returns, no changes).

While slower than DynamoDB, Amazon S3 certainly costs significantly less for storage!

Comment: For late readers like myself, I just want to point out that the cost advantage very much depends on the size of your payloads. This is because costs of S3 scale with requests whereas those of Dynamo scales with throughput. In my own scenarios (incl. on-demand), Dynamo can actually be cheaper for small payloads of 4kb or less. You can easily check this using https://calculator.aws/#/

Comment: If that's true, why wouldn't you use AWS S3 bucket instead of a NoSql db (e.g. mongoDB)?

Comment: Is Amazon S3 a database, or is it really something else? db-engines.com lists a number of Amazon products in it's list of databases. "S3" is not one of them. Is that because S3 is not really a database, or because S3 is actually built on something else?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant It all depends on your definition of a 'database'. For example, Amazon Athena is a 'query engine' that lets you use SQL on files stored in S3 buckets. Data is not 'loaded' into Athena, but it acts just like a normal database. So, is it a database, or a 'query engine'? S3 is not a database in the traditional sense (although **S3 Select** does provide SQL access to individual files), but it definitely _is_ a 'NoSQL database' or key-value store. The Cloud is changing previous conceptions -- networks are now virtual, databases are serverless, simple definitions are gone.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Sure I get that - I was more asking in terms of the technology it runs on. I understand your point that increasingly these "databases" are not databases but interfaces to other backend storage systems, each of which might present a different "API" effectively - basically my question is "what is S3" (in terms of technology). Is it just an interface to some other backend storage system, ...., etc...?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant The answer, as with most things in the cloud, is: "It doesn't matter." Cloud services are effectively black boxes. As long as they present a known interface/API, it doesn't matter how it is actually implemented. Amazon S3 was first released in 2006 and has probably been totally rewritten several times since then. It is the first (only?) storage service to store such a volume of data and handle so many requests. No pre-existing system would have been able to handle these requirements. It also uses large amounts of hardware in each Region and lots of storage devices.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein This is slightly tangental to my last question, but presumably S3 is actually some kind of protocol? Is it Amazon's own creation or did S3 exist as a protocol/API before Amazon wrote their own implementation of it?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Amazon invented S3 and the whole concept of cloud storage -- see [Amazon S3 | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon_s3/). For the first 10 years of AWS, the IT industry dismissed Cloud Computing as an irrelevant technology, but then they all raced to catch-up. In fact, pretty much all cloud providers now provide a storage API that is a copy of the S3 API. This shows that AWS led the way in cloud storage and cloud computing.

Answer (score 40):

Context: we use S3 for some "database" (*lit.* key/value structured storage).

It should be noted that S3 does actually have search and, depending on how you structure your data, queries in the form of [S3 Select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/) (and, if you have the time: Athena).

Edit: prior to December, 2020, S3 was eventually consistent. [Now it it is **strongly consistent**](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/). Following disadvantages doesn't apply anymore, but are here for historical reasons.

---

Before December, 2020, the biggest disadvantage/architectural challenge was that S3 was eventually consistent (which was actually the reason why you could not "update" a file). This manifested itself in some behaviours which your architecture needed to tolerate:

- Operations were cached by key, so if you attempted to get an object that doesn't exist, and then create it- for a period of time* any gets on that object will return that it does not exist.
- There was no global cache, so you could get two different versions of the same object for a period of time* after it has been overwritten.
- List operations provided a semi-unstable iterator. If you were going to *list* on a large number of objects in a bucket that was being updated, then chances are you were not going to visit all the objects by the end of the iterator.

**period of time is purposely undefined by AWS, however, from observation, it is rarely more than a minute.*

Comment: what do you mean with "There is no global cache, so you can get two different versions of the same object for a period of time* after it has been overwritten." if its eventually consistent, shouldnt this be possible?

Comment: This has been addressed 

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/